# How to use NHibernate DtachedCriteria sub queries to filter by list of referenced entities properties?

Tags: nhibernate, subquery, nhibernate-criteria, detachedcriteria

I want the outcome to be a single sql statement.
I have the following structure:

```
public class B
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int BNumber { get; set; }
}
public class A
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<B> Bs { get; set; }
    public virtual int ANumber { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a detached criteria that filters A's by numbers higher then 6:

```
DetachedCriteria.For<A>().Add(Restrictions.Gt("ANumber", 6))
                         .Add(Subqueries.???).List<A>();
```

I want to add a filter that will return only A's that contains B's with Number lower then 5. How do I do it? I want this as generic as possible so I can reuse it in multiple places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DetachedCriteria.For<A>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Gt("ANumber", 6))
    .CreateCriteria("Bs")
        .Add(Restrictions.Lt("BNumber", 5))
    .List<A>();
```

Update: having an Or from different subqueries

```
DetachedCriteria.For<A>()
    .Add(Restrictions.Gt("ANumber", 6))
    .CreateAlias("Bs", "b")
    .CreateAlias("Cs", "c")
    .Add(Restrictions.Or(
        Restrictions.Lt("b.Number", 5),
        Restrictions.Lt("c.Number", 5))
    .List<A>();
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I wanted to use more the 1 subquery? Am I supposed to assign the CreateCriteria("Bs") resut to a parameter and CreateCriteria("Cs") result to a different parameter and use Restrictions.Or?

Comment: then use CreateAlias("property", "alias") and Restrictions.Or(... "alias.Property"...)

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do it for 2 subqueries and filter by their id numbers? (Assuming I'm using the structure in the question)? I'm not sure what exacly goes in the "Or" function call.